# setting process for command button inside a dialogue gives blank value

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, process, primefaces, dialog

Setting `process="@this"` inside a `<p:dialog>` will hit the method in managedBean but the submitted values are empty. Setting `process="@form"` does not hit a method. Setting `process="@all"` gives `null` values. Setting a nested form, introducing a form in a dialogue is not advisable. What do I have to specify in the `process` attribute?

```
<p:commandButton id="serachInsideDialogue" value="#{msg.AddSystem_searchLabel}"  action="#{testBean.edit}" update="growl" process="@this">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{testBean.searchUserId}" value="#{testBean1.searchId}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with some functions like that

```
   function null() { document.getElementById("serachInsideDialogue").style.display= ""; }
```

and then to customize them as you want for every event.

And them to call them in your process when you want like events.

Answer (score 0):

> *Introducing a form in a dialogue is not advisable*

You have been misinformed.

The dialog must not be placed inside any form. Instead, it must be placed outside any form and in turn have its own form. You obviously don't want to process all other inputs inside the same form outside the dialog when intending to submit the inputs in the dialog.

Once you fix that, you can just use `process="@form"` which is already the default value and can thus safely be omitted altogether.